# Multi-channel BCI to support high range of brain waves with good API/SDK

Tags: brain-computer-interface

I'm looking for [BCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain%E2%80%93computer_interface) (a brain–computer interface) device with high-range sensitive multi-channel sensors with API in order to program few smart apps/games.

I was playing with XWave headset by PLX, but it simply didn't work as expected. It was quite often complaining the signal was low (batteries or device weren't faulty, as I had them few), secondly it supported only one channel (as far as I remember) so the sample apps didn't work well, but it was some time ago, so I believe things has been change since then.

What cutting-edge headset would you recommend nowadays?

It needs to have API/SDK with good community support and have outstanding multi-channel sensors, so my app is not limited by the device it-self.